# Invoke-RestMethod Patch throws error in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am running in issue with updating Intune Device Scripts. My code works when I run through VS code on local machine but errors out when running through Azure DevOps Pipeline.

$updateURI:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceManagementScripts/c24***********6a

$postbody:

```
{
    $Resource = "deviceManagementScripts"
    $ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.deviceManagementScript"
    $postbody = @{
        "@odata.type" = $ODataType; 
        "displayName" = $Displayname;
        "description" = $Description;
        "scriptContent" = $UploadScriptEncoded;
        "runAsAccount" = "user";
        "enforceSignatureCheck" = "false";
        "fileName" = $Filename } | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

RestMetthod:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateURI -Headers $authHeader -Method Patch -Body $postbody -ContentType "application/JSON"
```

ERROR:

Invoke-RestMethod: /Users/runner/work/1/s/inline.ps1:111
Line |
111 |  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateURI -Headers $authHeader -Method Patch  …
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  "_version":
| 3,\r\n  "Message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID
| (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -
| Activity ID: c27be3e1-4de1-43c2-8f5d-9db86608b2a7 - Url:
| [https://fef.amsua0202.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/deviceManagementScripts%28%274ce72c8b-1086-404d-8c9f-db9ff8b95d35%27%29?api-version=5021-03-18\",\r\n](https://fef.amsua0202.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/deviceManagementScripts%28%274ce72c8b-1086-404d-8c9f-db9ff8b95d35%27%29?api-version=5021-03-18%5C%22,%5Cr%5Cn)  "CustomApiErrorPhrase": "",\r\n  "RetryAfter": null,\r\n  "ErrorSourceService": "",\r\n  "HttpHeaders": "{}"\r\n}","innerError":{"date":"2021-04-23T21:42:36","request-id":"c27be3e1-4de1-43c2-8f5d-9db86608b2a7","client-request-id":"c27be3e1-4de1-43c2-8f5d-9db86608b2a7"}}}

##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

XML:

```
<ODataError xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.OData.Core">
<Details i:nil="true"/>
<ErrorCode>UnsupportedApiVersion</ErrorCode>
<InnerError i:nil="true"/>
<InstanceAnnotations/>
<Message>{ "_version": 3, "Message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: d7777c39-60cd-46e3-bca0-a24148d2ccb6 - Url: https://fef.amsua0202.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/deviceManagementScripts%28%274ce72c8b-1086-404d-8c9f-db9ff8b95d35%27%29?api-version=5021-03-18%5C%22,%5Cr%5Cn", "CustomApiErrorPhrase": "", "RetryAfter": null, "ErrorSourceService": "", "HttpHeaders": "{}" }</Message>
<Target i:nil="true"/>
</ODataError>
```

Please help here in understanding what am I missing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try deleting the `@odata.type` parameter in the `$postbody` and running it again.